# Fix compile time error with Kotlin 1.8.10

Tags: android, kotlin

In an Android app I'm using `Kotlin 1.7.20` and I'm trying to switch to `Kotlin 1.8.10` but I'm getting the error:

> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':useraction:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
>   'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.FileUtilsKt.cleanDirectoryContents(java.io.File)'
> - Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.

Unfortunately it isn't clear what is triggering the call to `cleanDirectoryContents`.
I know that `Kotlin 1.8.0` introduced a change around that features but I didn't find any tutorial for the migration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a problem with the gradle cache although I can't be sure.
When I upgraded the gradle wrapper to `7.6` from `7.3.3` suddenly it started working. I tried to reverse the change to reproduce the issue again and I couldn't.
I can't really point to the thing that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that your kotlin version in your toml is compatible with what you're using in the project toplevel declaration (i.e.)

Project:
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false

Toml:
kotlin = "1.9.22"